# Azure, java sdk, Deploying with ARM template - failure to convert Parameter file

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to write a java JUnit test that will deploy template-defined resource groups using the java-sdk for azure.

I came across a couple examples and followed them to create this code segment:

```
public void azurePoC() throws Exception {

    Azure azure = Azure.configure()
            .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY)
            .authenticate(new File("C:/somePath/credentials.azure"))
            .withDefaultSubscription();

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode template = mapper.readTree(new File("C:/somePath/template.json"));

    Logger.report("template", template.toString());

    JsonNode params = mapper.readTree(new File("C:/somePath/parameters.json"));
    Logger.report("params", params.toString());

    azure.deployments()
            .define("myNewResource")
            .withNewResourceGroup("myNewResourceGroup", Region.US_WEST2)
            .withTemplate(template)
            .withParameters(params)
            .withMode(DeploymentMode.INCREMENTAL)
            .create();

    Logger.report("Request for deployment done.");
}
```

I have verified that the API allows me to lookup resources using `azure.virtualMachines().list()` method, therefore i conclude that my credentials are okay.

I am using one of the quick-start templates to for my PoC, just to see if i can deploy some resource.

My template.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "User name for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "16.04.0-LTS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "12.04.5-LTS",
        "14.04.5-LTS",
        "15.10",
        "16.04.0-LTS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'salinuxvm')]",
    "imagePublisher": "Canonical",
    "imageOffer": "UbuntuServer",
    "nicName": "myVMNic",
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "Subnet",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "publicIPAddressName": "myPublicIP",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "vmName": "MyUbuntuVM",
    "vmSize": "Standard_A1",
    "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "hostname": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    },
    "sshCommand": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat('ssh ', parameters('adminUsername'), '@', reference(variables('publicIPAddressName')).dnsSettings.fqdn)]"
    }
  }
}
```

My parameters.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "ghuser"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "GEN-PASSWORD"
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I run the application I am confronted with this exception:

```
com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.$schema', line 1, position 4459.'.: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.$schema', line 1, position 4459.'.
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.createExceptionFromResponse(AzureClient.java:740)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient.access$100(AzureClient.java:33)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:160)
at com.microsoft.azure.AzureClient$3.call(AzureClient.java:157)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:81)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle.call(OnSubscribeSingle.java:27)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:39)
at rx.internal.operators.SingleToObservable.call(SingleToObservable.java:27)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.DeferredScalarSubscriber.subscribeTo(DeferredScalarSubscriber.java:153)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:32)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:22)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
... 43 more
```

Any and all help in the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share your parameters file?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I edited it in, thank you for taking the time to consider my problem

Comment: What template are you using in the marketplace?  The published VSec one doesn't allow for that version (unless you modified it)…  I'm not 100% certain that's your error, but I wouldn't expect that template and the above params to work as is...

Comment: I've used a couple of templates and a couple of parameter files. my example was simply the last one i've tried. In all instances i was trying to deploy a management server (there are 3 types on the marketplace, all produced the same error).
I've also tried various mixes of "Exiting resource group" and "new resource group". all other resourced that are named have been manually created through the protal

Comment: I'd also like to add, out of frustration, that if this error originates due to some mismatch between parameter-template definition than it is the worst and most undescriptive error I've ever encountered.

Comment: can you try deploying something like this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-linux, also seconding what @bmoore-msft said, parameters file looks fine

Comment: I'll try that first thing Sunday morning, i've no access to my workstation until than.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.$schema', line 1, position 4459.'.  Same error, i am using azure sdk version 1.18.0.

Comment: Updated to azure sdk version 1.19.0, did not solve the problem.

Comment: The template you have above is fine... in the param file the two GEN params are not going to work, but you're not getting that far.  The error you're getting suggests something wrong your request - what you're parsing for parameters.  If the code above (template and params) are not working then it's somewhere in your deployment code/method.

Comment: @bmoore-msft care to share me an example of how the deployment code should look like, a method that reads the .json files included? that will be greatly appreciated since this code is already based on examples i found on the official azure git

Comment: I'm not familiar with the java sdk, but if you go to the portal and click the Automation Script blade for a resource group there are a few examples there of how to deploy a template using tools.  This also might help: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-java-deploy-using-arm-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question.

Turns out the problem was the parameter file json syntax.
The schema, parameters and version fields are redundant

this is the expected syntax using Azure Java SDK:

```
{
  "adminUsername": {
    "value": "ghuser"
  },
  "adminPassword": {
    "value": "GEN-PASSWORD"
  },
  "dnsLabelPrefix": {
    "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
  }
}
```

Comment: I was following this https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-account-create sample template and it did not work. You solution worked for me. Thanks